# how to put the item id on console.log using add to cart button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

This is my html button for add to cart and below that is the JavaScript code I am using to display the `itemdetails` id into the browser console of google chrome.

```
 {% for detail in tonerdetails %}

      <tr>
          <td>{{detail.toner_model.toner_model}}</td>

          <td>{{detail.issued_to.name}}</td>
          <td>{{detail.employee_name}}</td>
          <td>{{detail.employee_designation}}</td>
          <td>{{detail.status}}</td>
          <td><a href="{% url 'print_toner_issue_vouchers' detail.id %}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="btn btn-info">Print Issue Voucher</a>
              <a href="{% url 'print_toner_sent_invoice' detail.id %}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="btn btn-info">Print Invoice</a>

              <a data-detail="{{detail.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary addtocart">Add to Cart</a>
              <a href="{% url 'edit_tonerdetails_form' detail.id %}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
              <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal{{ toner.pk }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
```

```js
let butns=document.getElementsByClassName('addtocart')
for (btn of butns){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let detailid=this.dataset.detail
        let action=this.dataset.action
        console.log(detailid)
    })
}
```

Comment: What issue you're facing it should log **detailid** when you click on **Add to Cart** button

Comment: @AnkitTiwari i want to display the detailid but the browser console doesn't display anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo inside your **JavaScript** you were listening event on `butns` array not on each element of that array so I changed it to `btn.addEventListener` and it should be

```
let action=this.dataset.action
```

instead of

```
let action=this.dataser.action
```

Here is working example

```js
let butns=document.getElementsByClassName('addtocart')
for (let btn of butns){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let detailid=this.dataset.detail
        let action=this.dataset.action
        console.log(detailid)
    })
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<a data-detail="1" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary addtocart">
Add to Cart - 1
</a>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<a data-detail="2" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary addtocart">
Add to Cart - 2
</a>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<a data-detail="3" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary addtocart">
Add to Cart - 3
</a>
</tr>
</table>
```

### Update

Turns out above solution is not working for you here is one more approch to solve your problem

```js
function getCartData(detailId, action){
  console.log(detailId)
  console.log(action)
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<a onclick="getCartData(1, 'add-one')" class="btn btn-outline-secondary addtocart">
Add to Cart - 1
</a>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<a onclick="getCartData(2, 'add-two')" class="btn btn-outline-secondary addtocart">
Add to Cart - 2
</a>
</tr><br>
<tr>
<a onclick="getCartData(3, 'add-three')" class="btn btn-outline-secondary addtocart">
Add to Cart - 3
</a>
</tr>
</table>
```

in above example you've to pass your `getCartData('{{detail.id}}', 'add')`

Comment: unfortunately its still not outputting the detailid.

Comment: You can see my working example it's outputing detailid. Can you update your question by making an [edit] based on current code changes

Comment: i have made the edits based on your code.

Comment: Hello @muneermohd9690 what you get inside your console did you receved any errors ?

Comment: no error.thats the problem.atleast if i am able to see something i can google on that. but here theres nothing.

Comment: I think your javascript is not rendered correctly inspect your **HTML** code in browser and check if there is javascript which you've written

Comment: i did that i wrote a cosole.log to display hello mesage in the same script and it display it properly.but when it comes to this add to cart script the it doesn't work.do you want to get a session using anydesk or something?

Comment: Yes, let's connect on anydesk give me your id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247422/discussion-between-muneermohd9690-and-ankit-tiwari).